# Prevent some elements from being rendered canvas

Tags: jquery, attributes, html2canvas

[This](http://gta4you.esy.es/) is my website.

I want the background of my nav-element to be blurred... I used html2canvas and stackblur for this, and you can find [the tutorial here](http://jsfiddle.net/nallenscott/WtQjY/41/).

My problem is now that I want to exclude the nav-element from being rendered in canvas, so it only shows the background when scrolling. Currently it’s only working in [WebKit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebKit) browsers, because I don’t know how to add multiple properties to:

> "-webkit-transform",

This is my code:

```
<script>
    $(function () {
        html2canvas($("body"), {
            onrendered: function (canvas) {
                $("div.blurnav, div.blurnav.small").append(canvas);
                $("canvas").attr("id", "canvas");
                stackBlurCanvasRGB(
                    'canvas',
                    0,
                    0,
                    $("canvas").width(),
                    $("canvas").height(),
                    20);
                }
        });
        vv = setTimeout(function () {
            $("body").show();
            clearTimeout(vv);
        }, 200);
    });

    $(window).scroll(function () {
        $("canvas").css(
            "-webkit-transform",
            "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
    });

    window.onresize = function () {
        $("canvas").width($(window).width());
    };

    $(document).bind('touchmove', function () {
        $("canvas").css(
            "-webkit-transform",
            "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
    });

    $(document).bind('touchend', function () {
        $("canvas").css(
            "-webkit-transform",
            "translatey(-" + $(window).scrollTop() + "px)");
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I found this in html2canvas updates: *[Added support for "data-html2canvas-ignore" attribute](https://github.com/niklasvh/html2canvas/commit/7c0b893564ea139005405b22d2ece99588663d7f)*

For preventing render of a DOM element, you need add the `data-html2canvas-ignore` attribute in your element:

```js
var test = document.getElementById("test");
var content = document.getElementById("content");

test.onclick = function () {
    html2canvas(content, {
        "onrendered": function(canvas) {
            document.body.appendChild(canvas);
        }
    });
};
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html2canvas/0.4.1/html2canvas.min.js"></script>

<p>
  <a id="test" href="javascript:void(0);">test</a>
</p>

<div id="content">
    <div class="element-1">1. Is visible</div>
    <div class="element-2" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">2. No visible</div>
    <div class="element-3">3. Is visible</div>
</div>
```

Comment: It is ignoring that div but it is adding extra whitespace for that div.

Comment: @MuneemHabib yes, he has to make the space, because this space is just to keep the other elements, this is like a `vibility:hidden` and not a `display:none`. If you want to completely remove an element from the rendering before running html2canvas just apply display: none and after the `onrendered` event remove the `display:none`.

Answer (score 6):

Let us say you want to hide the following div.

```
<div class="SomeClassOfYours" id="sampleDiv">
```

Then, just add the following line in the div.

```
<div class="SomeClassOfYours" id="sampleDiv" data-html2canvas-ignore="true">
```

And that's it! Your problem is solved.